# jQuery Print Index of Table Cell

Tags: jquery

I'm doing homework and have everything perfect, except I cannot get the index number to print out for each cell. For Example, each cell should say "Cell 0", "Cell 1", etc to the end.

I'm very new to jQuery and cannot figure out what my issue is. Any help would be appreciated!

```
        for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {               
            var tableData = document.createElement("td");
            (tableData).innerHTML = "cell ";
            $("tr").append(tableData);
            $("td").append().index();
        }
```

Comment: What's the code sample you provided supposed to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it'll help:

```
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {               
            var tableData = document.createElement("td");
            (tableData).innerHTML = "cell "+ i; // here is change
            $("tr").append(tableData);
        }
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4ca0xs9/)